# Optimal way to setup user account / accesses?

Tags: users, account-restrictions, access-control

I have a (home) Ubuntu machine; upon installation I created the "x" user during the installation (who is not the root) so often when I want to run apt-get or other things that require write access to `/usr` or `/var` I need to sudo.

My question is is there a safe way to setup the "x" user in such a way that he has more rights so that I don't have to sudo or su?

What would be the optimal way to do the user account management? (On a home machine - so no production.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not on Linux. On Solaris you can use RBAC (Role Based Access Control) and provide additional permissions.

On Linux the proper way to do this is to use `sudo`.

We all do it.
That is the way of things.
The way of the *Force*.

Comment: love the ending quote :) so you should have a normal account to run X and normal stuff, and when it comes to system stuff you sudo. What about /var/www/ if you want to have a website and edit the .html or .php files without sudo-ing?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Change the ownership (or the group) of `/var/www`.

Comment: with the chown command I image? So I should put the ownership to the simple user? would that open 'holes' in case someone wanted to 'hack' the website? (sorry if this sounds silly)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos: On the contrary. It's *more* secure to have `/var/www` owned by an unprivileged user. Having it owned by `root` or `www-data` is unsafe.

Comment: This is basically right, but should note that `sudo` can be configured to not prompt for a password for specific (or even all) commands.